# Problem displaying incoming text from mySql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, unicode

[image]

**This utf8 problem bothered me again**

It's ok on the other pages, but it can't show it on this page

---

### I tried the following methods but it did not work

- `mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");`
- `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
- [image]

Comment: utf8_* isn't the UTF-8, you should use utf8mb4_*

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8` shouldn't be used from PHP. Set the correct connection charset using the API methods provided, e.g. `mysqli::set_charset()`

Comment: omg!! A small dash sign had delayed me for hours. i use `SET NAMES utf-8` And the problem was solved

Comment: I sincerely doubt it, because that's not a valid syntax. Anyway, you must remove `SET NAMES` completely from your code.

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored